# jquery not selector with nested elements

Tags: jquery

If I have some elements like:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to do something when a user clicks one but NOT two:

```
$('.one:not(.two)').live('click', function(){
            console.log('jazz');     
        });
```

But it still does the console log... because the element is nested! How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer to bind a separate click event to `two`, to tell browser to stop event bubbling, imho, it's much more readable that way:

```
$('.one').click(function() {
   console.log('jazz');
})
.find('.two').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for

```
$('.one:not(:has(.two))')
```

Alternatively, you can handle the event on `.one`, then handle it on `.two` and call `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent it from bubbling up to `.one`.